# javascript drag and drop by offset

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop element by offset (350,0) using only javascript
for example,  The picture below is the action I want

Drag and drop element:

[image]

1. drag the stackoverflow mark by 350 on the X axis
2. and drop it

   ```
   <span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>
   ```

I thought someone would have asked a similar question, but I could not find it.
Who can tell me a example?

Comment: Did you tried [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_draggable)?

Comment: you can try the following eamples - 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

https://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/78jwe/